# Set segmented control's index based on segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

I am going form one controller to another using several different uibuttons and segues. I want to set my segmented control to start at a specified index based on the segue used. I have attempted the code below but receive an error when I run the app.

Code:

```
if segue.identifier == "watchedSegue" {
        if let detailView = segue.destination as? ListView {
            detailView.watchList = watchList
            detailView.watchedList = watchedList
            detailView.listSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 //Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        }
    }
```

Why am I receiving this error when running the app? What is the preferred way of setting default index based on segue?

Comment: you can assign selected index value to a int property declare in destination folder in prepare for segue, as segment  is nil that point, then you can assign the value to segment in viewwillApear method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comment from [M Abubaker Majeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3142451/m-abubaker-majeed) I Replaced:

```
detailView.listSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
```

with:

```
detailView.segIndex = 1
```

Then placed this into the segmented view controller:

```
var segIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

listSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = segIndex

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the only index into a variable like:

```
detailView.activeIndex = 1
```

And in the next view controller, you can simply set segment index in ViewDidLoad().

Note: It's crashing in your given question because at that point segment controller is nil.